# Possible way to write below code in java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a code, which is working as required, but I want to re-write it in Java 8.

This code will produce a map.Each list item will have all the servers allocated to it.

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> agg(){
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Item A", "Item B", "Item C");
        List<String> servers = Arrays.asList("Server A", "Server B", "Server C", "Server D");
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < servers.size(); j++) {
                temp.add(servers.get(j));
            }
            map.put(list.get(i), temp);
        }
        return map;
    }
```

**Output**

```
Item C ::[Server A, Server B, Server C, Server D]
Item B ::[Server A, Server B, Server C, Server D]
Item A ::[Server A, Server B, Server C, Server D]
```

What would be the lambda equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify code before converting it to lambda expressions

```
 public static Map<String, List<String>> agg(){
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Item A", "Item B", "Item C");
    List<String> servers = Arrays.asList("Server A", "Server B", "Server C", "Server D");
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        map.put(list.get(i), new ArrayList<>(servers));
    }
    return map;
}
```

I just simplified creating an array copy.

The pipeline to convert from a form of data to another in Java 8 contains the following steps:

1. stream
2. map (convert from a form to another)
3. reduce (filter out unwanted values)
4. collect (collect results)

Because your data does not need to be converted, just collected in a different structure, map and reduce are not needed

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> agg(){
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Item A", "Item B", "Item C");
    List<String> servers = Arrays.asList("Server A", "Server B", "Server C", "Server D");

    Function<String, String> keyFunction = key -> key;
    Function<String, List<String>> valueFunction = key -> new ArrayList<>(servers);

    return list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(keyFunction, valueFunction));
}
```

Those functions can be inlined and the result would be:

```
    public static Map<String, List<String>> agg(){
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Item A", "Item B", "Item C");
    List<String> servers = Arrays.asList("Server A", "Server B", "Server C", "Server D");

    return list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key, key -> new ArrayList<>(servers)));
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but sorry I am unable to understand it. What happened to keyFunction and valueFunctions?

Comment: Understood your answer. But I have one question. Like you said we can have Stream, Map, Reduce & Collect operation. Let's say I want to append list name with each sever name, e.g: Item A_Server A, Item A_Server B ..., in that case how i will write map method?

Comment: In that case, you need to change the value function to something different. In this case you would need a map function to convert those values: Function<String, List<String>> valueFunction = key -> servers.stream().map(server -> key + "_" + server).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Thanks, I did the same thing.

Comment: Glad I could help. The streams are a powerful tool to be used in case you understand how they work.

Comment: correct, I am still learning Java 8. Do you have any references to learn from? If yes, please share.

Comment: I don't have a specific reference you can learn from, just some ideas to make the learning process easier: 1. Install an IDE that suggests changing existing code to Lambda expressions (like Intellij IDEA). Make sure you understand what happens in the new code. 2. Split your problems in stream -> map -> reduce -> collect flows and replace them with Lambda equivalent structures. 3. Search / ask questions on StackOverflow on how to solve specific scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Create a stream of your "items", and collect them into a map where the keys are the objects from that stream, and the values are copies of the server list.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

...

List<String> servers = Arrays.asList("Server A", "Server B", "Server C", "Server D");
Map<String, List<String>> map = Stream.of("Item A", "Item B", "Item C")
    .collect(toMap(Function.identity(), (__) -> new ArrayList<>(servers)));
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `forEach` approach would be

```
Map<String, List<String>> output = new HashMap<>();
list.forEach(s -> output.put(s, servers));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
list.stream()
            .map(item->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(item,servers))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: Nice approach!.There is one small possible issue: The list of servers is shared across multiple endpoints and can lead to unexpected issues further the line

Comment: @nucandrei what *exactly* do you mean?

Comment: If you alter the list in one place, those changes will be reflected for everybody using a reference to that list. There are two options to avoid this, unless it's the desired behavior: 1-Create a copy. 2-Use an immutable structure.